# Compare absolute values of two expressions!

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have two sets of numbers as follows:
 $$X = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}\\
 Y = \{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$$
And a number $r$.

Let $x^\ast$ and $y^\ast$ is average values of set $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

With the following conditions:
$|r-x_1|+|r-x_2|+...+|r-x_n|\geqslant|r-y_1|+|r-y_2|+...+|r-y_n|$
and
$|x^\ast-x_1|+|x^\ast-x_2|+...+|x^\ast-x_n|=|y^\ast-y_1|+|y^\ast-y_2|+...+|y^\ast-y_n|$

Whether the following statement is true:
$$|r-x^\ast| \geqslant |r-y^\ast|$$

Comment: Hint: consider the pairs $(x_k, y_k)$ to be points on a graph.  What is the geomentric meaning of the statements ?

Comment: An example that breaks the statement:  $n = 2$, $x_1 = -3, x_2 = 1, x^* = -1$, $y_1 = -1, y_2 = 3, y^* = 1$, $r = x^* = -1$.  Then, $|r-x_1|+|r-x_2| = 4 = |r - y_1| + | r - y_2|$, and $|x^* - x_1| + |x^* - x_2| = 4 = |y^* - y_1| + |y^* - y_2|$, but $|r - x^*| = 0 < |r - y^*| = 1$.

Comment: Some thoughts might help for problems like that.  1. You can assume $x_1 \le x_2 \le \dots \le x_n$, $y_1 \le y_2 \le \dots \le x_n$.  2. Second, for $x_i < x_{i+1}$, $|r - x_i| + |r - x_{i+1}|$ remains a constant (and the minimum value) if $x_i < r < x_{i+1}$.